# ng-bind or expression doesn't print

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind

Here is my scenario: 
(in controller)

```
var userData = $http(
{
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost/t-app/mobile-data/update-tasks.php",
    data: {
        done_tasks : $scope.done_tasks,
        job_id: $routeParams.job_id,
        employee_id: $scope.user_id,
        },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});

userData.success(function (userdataobject)
{
    $scope.message = userdataobject["message"];
    $scope.status_id = userdataobject["status_id"];

    $location.path("/taskStatus");

});
```

and now my route is like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/taskStatus', {templateUrl: 'partials/task-status.html'});
```

and my `task-status.html` is this:

```
<div ng-if="status_id == '1'" style="color:black">
    <h4 class="text-center" >{{message}}</h4>
    <div ng-bind="message"> </div>
    tum hi to ho
</div>

<div ng-if="status_id == '0'" style="color:black">
    <h4 class="text-center">{{message}}</h4>
    tum nhi ho 
    <div ng-bind="message"></div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is that on `task-status.html` I am not getting `{{message}}` expression as well as `ng-bind="message"`

Comment: Place a debugger in the succes function and check what's in the object.

Comment: And why are you putting the result on both $scope and $rootScope?

Comment: @yeouuu Thanks for indentifying, that was copying pasting error, I'ave edited it now..

Answer (score 2):

> Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is
>   in play. So, use   rather
>   than  .
>
> If you really want/need to use a primitive, there are two workarounds:
>
> 1. Use $parent.parentScopeProperty in the child scope. This will
>      prevent the child scope from creating its own property.
> 2. Define a function on the parent scope, and call it from the child,
>      passing
>          the primitive value up to the parent (not always possible)
>
> So instead of primitive type variable use object in angular. Always
>   prefer the following method.

In controller, create an object with those properties and use that.

```
$rootScope.commonObject={message:'',status_id:''}
$rootScope.commonObject.message = userdataobject["message"];
$rootScope.commonObject.status_id = userdataobject["status_id"];
```

In View,

```
<div ng-if="commonObject.status_id == '0'" style="color:black">
            <h4 class="text-center">{{commonObject.message}}</h4>
            tum nhi ho 
            <div ng-bind="commonObject.message"> </div>
        </div>
```

Refer : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Yes, You got it. I'ave changed it to `$rootScope.message` then it works. My friend can you please tell why $scope not works in this case?

Comment: If it works, then mark it as answer :-p ;-) . Actually you should do it in scope variable. Using scope variable, this will work. In case you need it to reflect in the whole application, you can use it in rootscope.

Comment: actually i dont wanna use it in my whole app.this is why i used `$scope`. But it don't work with `$scope` it is only working with `$rootScope`. The problem still here that i dont wanna this value to my whole app. value changes with respect to different modules..

Comment: Oh ok ok. Check the variable name with the case sensitive. Otherwise I need two help from you to identify the problem. I need your controller js file and the view file where the you have mentioned the the controller name. Second thing, If you can't paste your code, then create on jsfiddle and update your question. This will help us to identify the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
userData.success(function (userdataobject)
```

`userdataobject` has the next fields (from [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)):

- **data** – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- **status** – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
- **headers** – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
- **config** – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- **statusText** – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

Field `data` contains your response, so you need something like this:

```
 $scope.message = userdataobject.data["message"];
 $scope.status_id = userdataobject.data["status_id"];
```

Comment: Hi @IEaglle thanks for your answer. But now Im getting this error:
`Error: userdataobject.data is undefined
$scope.tasksubmit/`

Comment: @TechKid, `userData.success` was deprecated. Try to change to `userData.then`.